# Custom Template Notifications not working in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I'm using a custom template for my notification and when I do a test send of

```
{
    "title":"My Title",
    "message": "My message!",
}
```

I don't get to any of the code in my iOS solution, however the output window is showing:

```
2018-12-04 00:30:13.958 MYAPP.iOS[712:13982792] {
    aps =     {
        alert = "My message!";
    };
}
```

So the notification is being received but 1) not in the correct format and 2) not in the ProcessNotification function

any suggestions of what I might be missing?

Comment: Did it show on your device?

Comment: No it did not.   If the app is closed I see the notification pop up so I know the push part is working, but if the app is open I don't see anything on the device (just the text in the output window when I am debugging)

Comment: So the issue with the format of the message was because I had set up the registration incorrectly! It should have been:

var alertTemplate = "{\"aps\":{\"title\":\"$(title)\",\"alert\":\"$(message)\",\"params\":\"$(params)\"}}";
registration = new AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription(deviceHandle, alertTemplate);

Comment: However, the issue is when the app is up and running I'm not getting to any of the functions that handle the notifications.

If the app is running in the background or off it works because of
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidBecomeActiveNotification, DidBecomeActive);
but when the app is in the foreground nothing....